# Number format in Telerik grid

Tags: c#, telerik-mvc

I´m using Telerik grid with an update/edit option

When number is selected from db to a decimal variable it is on this format: 5.75

When i bind it to the grid it appear as: 5,75

When i push Edit button it appear in textbox as: 5,75

But when i push submit button it validates as: "The field Duration must be a number."

I have no format or decimal separator properties definded, for my culture format which is Icelandic, the comma separator is correct.

I'm asking how can i control on what format the number validates or appears in Telerik gridcontrol?

Are there some kind of numeric format controls that is can change in Telerik?

-agh

Answer (score 1):

You should use "globalize.js" from http://github.com/jquery/globalize

This solve your issue with number validation, i.e. "The field Duration must be a number."

For example

```
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Globalize/globalize.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Globalize/cultures/globalize.culture.de-DE.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) { return this.optional(element) || !isNaN(Globalize.parseFloat(value)); }
    $(function () {
        Globalize.culture('de-DE'); 
    });
</script>
```

or

```
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Globalize/globalize.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Globalize/cultures/globalize.culture." + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name + ".js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) { return this.optional(element) || !isNaN(Globalize.parseFloat(value)); }
    $(function () {
        Globalize.culture('@(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name)'); 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your culture info for the page in the code-behind?

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("is-IS");
```

This was the solution presented for both: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/culture-aware-number-formatting.aspx and http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/gridnumericcolumn-in-edit-mode-doesn-180-t-use-current-culture.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ok

Found the solution, you have to turn globalization on to enable regional number formatting on correct place.

This goes into the masterpage or _Layout.cshtml

```
@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().Globalization(true))
```

And this goes into the controller behind the page like HomeController.cs/Index

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("is-IS");
```

Because the asp parse machine uses comma instead of dot but the JQuery validation ignored that and used the default one which was Us-us or En-en

Solved !